# Why do some of a dwarf's labor preferences occasionally disappear when I add a new one?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm still a bit new to Dwarf Fortress and I've found that sometimes, when I add a labor preference to a dwarf, some other labor preference is automatically removed. Does this happen because of a limit to the number of labor preferences that a single dwarf can have, or for some other reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some labors conflict with each other because of equipment requirements. To my knowledge, only digging, woodcutting and hunting will conflict, because they require a pickaxe, an axe and a crossbow, respectively, so you can only have 1 of these 3 labors enabled for a dwarf at a time.

Comment: Ah, I see. So a single dwarf can only carry a pickaxe, an axe, *or* a crossbow, but no combination of the three?

Comment: They can carry exactly one weapon. Picks, axes and crossbows are weapons.

Comment: That's right, though you can equip as many weapons as you have arms in adventure mode, a dwarf can only use 1 in fortress mode.

Comment: Are you still restricted to two arms at most in adventure mode, or has Toady gotten those polymorph spells working?

Comment: @Shadur you can mod the game to use other races in adv mode or give yourself some playable race extra arms. Becoming a night creature might give you more arms too, I think.

Comment: Actually, you can equip as many weapons as you can carry in adventure mode, as long as you have a backpack. It's entirely possible to hold 12 halberds and 6 shields in one hand and still benefit from multigrasp.

Comment: @Samthere huh, I thought that only worked for shields.

Comment: @kotekzot Well, you'll still only be able to attack with one at a time, but it gives the advantage of having more attack modes. Not only does this allow you to pick the right type of strike for the moment, but also gives you more attacks which could each receive a combat opportunity for an aimed strike. With multigrasp weapons you have to shuffle things about so that you keep junk in your "empty" hand as you stack weapons and shields in your main hand, dropping it afterwards. It also leaves you at greater risk should you lose your wielding arm.

Comment: @kotekzot Also, if the first item in the hand is a ranged weapon, you can still fire with it!